# Pretty Print JSON-ish in List

Tags: android, json

So as a part of my Android application, I need to show a list that has information about all the sensors in the device.

Here is the code I am using to do the same.

```
//Read sensors and populate list
sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
sensor = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);

LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sensor_list, null);
ListView lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lv_sensor);

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(CollectActivity.this);
alertDialog.setView(convertView);
alertDialog.setTitle("Available Sensor List");
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter < Sensor > (CollectActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sensor));
alertDialog.show();
```

And the XML file is as simple as it can get viz.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lv_sensor"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

</ListView>
```

The output is like this (JSON-ish?):

[image: Sensor_out]

My question is, how can I pretty print it, that is making human readable with the least amount of code? Time limitation doesn't allow me to create another activity etc. with lots of parsing logic etc. 
**Edit:** The output is `json-ish`, as I wrote in the code. I was hoping there maybe some internal library that I may have missed!

Thanks.

Comment: Least amount of code? Gson has a pretty printer. If you want something even better, deserialize the objects and implement `toString`

Comment: But, actually, that isn't even valid JSON, so you might be out of luck.

Comment: @cricket_007 exactly, it's `json-ish`, as I wrote in the code. I was hoping there maybe some internal library that I missed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply write your own Adapter for `ArrayAdapter<Sensor>` (or use a RecyclerView)

What you see is not JSON, it is the `Sensor.toSrtring()` value. And one TextView is used for `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`

You have to create your own XML layout for the data you want to display, then implement `getView` in the Adapter to bind a `Sensor` object to the Views

Comment: I already knew this, I wished something easier may have existed. Maybe am out of luck.

Comment: You could try using dependency injection like Butterknife to reduce down code complexity. Adapters don't take that long to implement

Comment: True. Maybe I will just try to remove the special characters and be happy with it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sure. Strip the surrounding braces, then split on commas or equal signs... Regex extract values...  use a StringBuilder on the Sensor object variables. There are many options, but this is the most flexible IMO

Comment: I am trying but somehow it isn't working (still a novice :( ). Can you show me a small working example in this answer if you have time. I will be really grateful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Something like this, but you already have a model class, which is `Sensor`.  https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#using-a-custom-arrayadapter

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `GSON` library by Google!

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
```

Comment: How to I pass  `List<Sensor> sensor;` to Gson? Can you provide a sample snippet so I can mark this as answer? I have never used Gson before! Thanks.

Comment: @CodeWalker If you can get rid of the brackets and "s it certainly will!